# Getting an OSerror while installing any package or other software too

Tags: oserror, postgresql-16

recently I downloaded PostgreSQL for my project but I uninstalled it for some reason, but now I'm facing an error after uninstalled it "invalid path", on every installation of any package or software.
Please help me.
[Please look into this image for detailed error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf27o.png)

I didn't get this error so, don't know how to solve it.